# I'm using cameraX api for my app, How can I horizontally flip preview of viewfinder?

Tags: api, kotlin

I am using cameraX for my camera app project , I want to horizontally flip preview in viewFinder. I'm using PreviewView for viewfinder

I tried setRotation = -1f and it successfully worked for lower sdk version (api 22), but in newer device with I guess sdk version >27 , It is not working.